# Displaying SharePoint List items using Tabs in PowerApps Gallery

Tags: sharepoint, tabs, conditional-statements, powerapps

Per this brilliant instructional video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o2L0DADzKQ by Reza Dorrani I created collection colTabs to display different SharePoint List items in a PowerApps gallery. The OnStart property for App is this collection colTabs (smaller portion shown here):

```
ClearCollect(
colTabs,
{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "All States",
},
{
    ID: 2,
    Name: "East Coast",
},
{
    ID: 3,
    Name: "West Coast",
}
```

);

The "Name" from above are choice values from a SharePoint List regionsUSA.

So far in the main gallery I have the Items property as:

```
If(varTabSelected = 1, regionsUSA)
```

...and that is working fine displaying all items in the first tab. How do I expand the above If statement so that from the same SP List, if varTabSelected = 2, then only East Coast items are displayed, if varTabSelected = 3 only West Coast items are displayed and so on? Somehow I am having trouble pulling the choice items from the List so I am stuck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why write a dynamic filter statement instead?

```
Filter(regionsUSA,RegionName=LookUp(colTabs,varTabSelected=ID,Name))
```

If it gets a delegation warning, I'd try:

```
Switch(varTabSelected,1,Filter(regionsUSA, RegionName="All regions"),2,Filter...)
```

You can also achieve this using If, but it's even more typing:

```
If(varTabSelected=1,Filter(...), varTabSelected=2, Filter(...),...)
```

Comment: I applied your third option and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I attempted to Up vote I got this "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." so I'm not sure how to indicate you have provided the solution?